# serialVersionUID naming convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions, serializable

Is there any viable reason why serialVersionUID field is not named SERIAL_VERSION_UID?

According to the docs for [java.io.Serializable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.7.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly
>   by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be **static,
>   final**, and of type long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

While referring [Java Naming Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) all **static final** (constants) fields should be capitilized having its fragments separated with an underscore.

Comment: That's the way the serialization API is written ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Probably because serialVersionUID was defined in the Java serialization API before such conventions existed.</s>

I found a document published by Sun in 1997 called [Java Code Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf) that says in Section 9 on page 16 *"The names of variables declared class constants  and of ANSI 
    constants should be alluppercase with words separated by underscores (“*”)."_

So my guess is that Sun just didn't enforce their own standards on their own code.

Comment: Don't think so, serialVersionUID was introduced in Java 1.5

Comment: @WojtekOwczarczyk. It was introduced along with Serialization in Java 1.1.