# Java naming convenction and serialVersionUID(constant written in lowercase)

Tags: java, naming-conventions, serializable

Every serializable class has to declare a static final serialVersionUID field.
Due to the java naming convention every name of a constant should be written in uppercase.
But if I would name this variable for example as 'SERIAL_VERSION_UID' it would not work. 
Is this case a exception of the convention rule? Or may I somehow force my program to accept the uppercase name?

I found this question: [serialVersionUID naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836369/serialversionuid-naming-convention) But it did not provide me an answer. 
So is naming serialVersionUID is not a violation to a Naming Convetion Rules, and if yes, is there anywhere documented the prove of it?

Comment: What part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836406/1743880) does not answer this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [serialVersionUID naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836369/serialversionuid-naming-convention)

Comment: "The names of variables declared class constants and of ANSI constants should be alluppercase with words separated by underscores (“”)."_

serialVersionUID do not fulfill the rule, hence it is wrong naming and I shuld fix it. That is how I understood the answer to that question.
That is why I asked that question :(

Comment: TheLimeTrees, it is not a duplicate. I wrote it in my question, that I am not sure to the answer given here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836369/serialversionuid-naming-convention

Comment: Quoting "So my guess is that Sun just didn't enforce their own standards on their own code."

Comment: So the fact that user who gave the answer "is guessing is an answer? Is ok? There is no official solution to that problem? Using lowercase serialVersionUID is correct?

Comment: Is anywhere it's mentioned that serialVersionUID is a constant ?

Comment: Yes. In javadocs. -> docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html 'field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:''
Final variable is constant, am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

If you see Java Docs

*It is also strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not useful as inherited members*

So serialVersionUID  is not a constant and it's not used anywhere else in application. It Just a private member variable of a serialize class

Hope it will help

Comment: This does not mention anything about the naming convention which OP is asking for. It is just advising to use private modifier.

Comment: Is there anywhere it's written that serialVersionUID is a constant ?

Comment: Yes. In javadocs. -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html
'field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:''

Comment: Where it's say it is a constant ?

Comment: Here -> 'that must be static, final, and of type long'

Comment: if static final meas constant then why Java have 2 different keywords ? they could introduce 1 key word name "constant"

Comment: Because static != final.
Static means, that variable or method belongs to the class than instance of the class.
Final means that the entity may only be assigned once == it is constant.
serialVersionUID is both static & final.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91096/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-thamiar).